# Simplest diophantine equation with open solvability

Tags: diophantine-equations, problem-solving, existence-theorems

What is the simplest diophantine equation for which we (collectively) don't know whether it has *any* solutions? I'm aware of many simple ones where we don't know (whether we know) *all* the solutions, but all of these that I know have some solution.

Yes, I know that "simplest" is subjective. I'd be satisfied if it could be typeset in one line in a LaTeX document. Also, it would be nice if it could be easily memorized (no seven-digit numbers with nonobvious patterns:) though that's secondary.

Comment: $(x+1)(y+1)=2^{2^{1000}}+1$ [wanting solutions in positive integers only].

Comment: $x^5+y^5=z^5+w^5$ [positive integers, $\{\,x,y\,\}\ne\{\,z,w\,\}$].

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Determining which integers $n$ are a sum of three cubes is a very famous open problem:

$$a^3 + b^3 + c^3 = n, \quad a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}.$$
Conjecturally, $n$ is a sum of three cubes iff $n \not \equiv 4,5 \bmod 9$.

Note that this is really a family of Diophantine equations, rather than a single Diophantine equation.

Comment: The smallest open case now is $n=114$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sums_of_three_cubes#Computational_results

Comment: This one, together with @MattF.'s comment, fits most what I wanted. "Perfect cuboid" is nice over positive integers, but encoding positive integers themselves in Z really complicates the equation. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 22):

[*The perfect cuboid problem:*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_brick#Perfect_cuboid) We do not know if there is a common integer solution to
$$a^2+b^2+c^2=d^2$$

$$a^2+b^2=e^2$$
$$a^2+c^2=f^2$$
$$b^2+c^2=g^2$$
with $a,b,c \ge 1$.

The last condition can also be replaced with $abc=1+h^2+i^2+j^2+k^2$.

The equations can also be reduced from four or five to one, taking $\sum(LHS-RHS)^2=0$ as a single equation in 7 or 11 variables for which we don’t know any solutions.

Answer (score 13):

It's more complicated than the other answers by MattF and DanielLoughran, but the [Erdős–Straus conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Straus_conjecture) states that for every integer $n \ge 2$, there exist positive integers $x, y, z$ such that

$$\frac4n = \frac1x + \frac1y + \frac1z$$

Again, this is a *family* of Diophantine equations, related to [Egyptian fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_fraction), and computer research has verified the conjecture holds for all $n$ up to a rather large number, but whether it holds for *all* $n$ ($\ge 2$) is an open problem.

Comment: I'm sure that the smallest $n$ for which no solution is known is more than a 7-digit number.

Comment: @GerryMyerson In fact, it more than a 16-digit number..